# Perl "Out of memory!" when processing a large batch job

Tags: perl, out-of-memory, solaris

A few others and I are now the *happy* maintainers of a few legacy batch jobs written in Perl. About 30k lines of code, split across maybe 10-15 Perl files.

We have a lot of long-term fixes for improving how the batch process works, but in the short term, we have to keep the lights on for the various other projects that depend on the output of these batch jobs.

At the core of the main part of these batch jobs is a hash that is loaded up with a bunch of data collected from various data files in a bunch of directories. When these were first written, everything fit nicely into memory - no more than 100MB or so. Things of course grew over the years, and the hash now grows up to what the box can handle (8GB), leaving us with a nice message from Perl:

`Out of memory!`

This is, of course, a poor design for a batch job, and we have a clear (long-term) roadmap to improve the process.

I have two questions however:

- What kind of short-term options can we look at, short of throwing more memory at the machine? Any OS settings that can be tweaked? Perl runtime/compile flags that can be set?
- I'd also like to understand WHY Perl crashes with the "out of memory!" error, as opposed to using the swap space that is available on machine.

For reference, this is running on a Sun SPARC M3000 running Solaris 10 with 8 cores, 8 GB RAM, 10 GB swap space.

The reason throwing more memory at the machine is not really an ideal solution is mostly because of the hardware it's running on. Buying more memory for these Sun boxes is crazy expensive compared to the x86 world, and we probably won't be keeping these around much longer than another year.

The long-term solution is of course refactoring a lot of the codebase, and moving to Linux on x86.

Comment: A 32-bit version of perl on Solaris will crap out at around 3.7GB, regardless of whatever memory the system has.

Comment: All the general recommendations about not slurping etc apply. However, please show at least the general structure of the hash. If you have a complex data structure, see if you can't convert some of the array or hashrefs into strings which you expand as needed.

Comment: You could try `tie`ing the hash to a [`DBM::Deep`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBM::Deep#Tie-Construction) object. Be sure to read the warnings about infinite loops in the docs, though.

Comment: Worth checking ulimit to make sure the perl processes are not being prematurely limited

Answer (score 1):

There aren't really any generally-applicable methods of reducing a program's memory footprint; it takes someone familiar with Perl to scan the code and find something relevant to your specific situation

You may find that storing your hash as a disk-based database helps, and the more general way is to use [`Tie::Hash::DBD`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::DBD) which will allow you to use any database that `DBI` supports, but it won't help with hashes whose values can be references, such as nested hashes. (As `ThisSuitIsBlackNot` has commented, [`DBM::Deep`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBM::Deep) overcomes even this obstacle.)

I presume your Perl code is crashing at startup? If you have a memory leak then it should be simpler to find the cause. Alternatively it may be obvious to you that the initial population of the hash is wasteful in that it is storing data that will never be used. If you show that part of your code then I am sure someone will be able to assist

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 64bit version of interpreter. I had the same issue with "Out of memory" message. In my case 32bit strawberry perl ate 2Gb of RAM before termination. 64bit version of interpreter can use bigger amount. It ate the rest of my 16Gb and than started to swap like hell. But I received a result.